# What happens in terms of memory if I detach an object in a structure

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa, ipad, cocoa-touch

Suppose this situation. I have a Person class with these properties:

- parent (weak) - holds a reference to the person parent object
- children (strong) - is an array of children of that person
- director - boolean holding a flag to mark if the person is a director in a hierarchy

Then I have an array of employees. Only the CEOs of all branches of that company are added to that array. Employees are added as children to their respective bosses with different levels of hierarchy.

Visually something like this (in this example you only see one CEO added to the array):

```
      JACK (CEO)
          |
   ---------------       
   |              |
  BOB            TOM  
                  |
                  |
              ---------
             |         |
            LAURA    CARRY 
                       |  
                      TONY
```

Look at the right branch. Tony is child of Carry that is one of the children of Tom that is child of Jack. Every person holds a strong reference to its child and a weak reference to its parent.

What happens in terms of memory, if I remove Tom from Jack's children array? The whole branch Tom, Laura, Carry and Tony are released from the memory or do I have to break all links between every element, for example, between Carry and Tony, between Tom and its children, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole branch is released; you don't need to do any more work.

In practice, what's happening is that when Tom is released from Jack's ownership, it in turn will release any strong references that it is holding on to, which happens recursively down the tree of references.

Comment: Thanks, when I saw that deleting an object from the three would be easier than I thought I doubt it for a second and thought it could be a "trick" from iOS to screw me...  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A small experiment

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


@interface Person : NSObject
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString * name;
@property (strong , nonatomic) NSMutableArray *children;
@property (weak, nonatomic) Person *parent;
@end

@implementation Person

- (instancetype)initWithName:(NSString *)name
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _name = name;
        _children = [@[] mutableCopy];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)dealloc
{
    NSLog(@"dealloc %@", self.name);
}
@end


int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    //family's scope is the main function. it will exist till the app stops.
    NSMutableArray *family = [@[] mutableCopy];

    @autoreleasepool {

        Person *p0 = [[Person alloc] initWithName:@"father"];
        Person *c1 = [[Person alloc] initWithName:@"child 1"];
        Person *c2 = [[Person alloc] initWithName:@"child 2"];
        [p0.children addObject:c1];
        [p0.children addObject:c2];

        [family addObject:p0];
        [family removeObjectAtIndex:0];
        // p0, c1, c2 are defined in this scope. but family is defined 
        // in the scope of main()
    }
    while (YES) { // needed to give NSLog enough time
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If you run this code, it will yield

```
2015-02-20 18:50:40.618 persons[66846:956945] dealloc father
2015-02-20 18:50:40.619 persons[66846:956945] dealloc child 1
2015-02-20 18:50:40.619 persons[66846:956945] dealloc child 2
```

if you remove `[family removeObjectAtIndex:0];` nothing will be printed.

The rule is: as long as an object is referenced strongly by another, it will not be released. If no more strong reference is present, it will be deallocated. the scope where it is defined has a strong reference (that is why I wrapped the code in an autorelease pool, otherwise the main function would be the scope).